# Post Data from android to mysql through codeigniter

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter, gps

I am trying to create an android app that gets my current location (latitude and longitude) and i'm trying to send the data to mysql database via http post but my php side doesn't seem to receive the data i am sending and will not insert into the database.

i am using localhost and i have tried accessing the link via phone browser and it works fine.

**Geolocation.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    textlat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlat);
    textlong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlong);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

    InputStream is = null;
    Location lastLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (lastLocation != null)
    {
        textlat.setText(Double.toString(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
        textlong.setText(Double.toString(lastLocation.getLongitude()));

        double pLong1 = lastLocation.getLongitude();
        double pLat1 = lastLocation.getLatitude();


        String lat = String.valueOf(pLat1);
        String lng = String.valueOf(pLong1);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String postURL = "http://192.168.254.100/capstone/vehiclemonitoring/coordinates";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
         is = resEntity.getContent();

            String msg = "Data entered successfully";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
 class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();


                String lat = String.valueOf(pLat);
                String lon = String.valueOf(pLong);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lon));

                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String postURL = "http://192.168.254.100/capstone/vehiclemonitoring/coordinates";
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
                    post.setEntity(ent);
                    HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                    if (resEntity != null) {
                        Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    textlat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textlong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

     }
```

coordinates.php

```
function coordinates(){
if(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) && isset($_REQUEST['lng'])){

    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];

    echo "OK";
 }else{
echo "not ok";
}
$this->vm_model->insertcoordinates($lat,$lng);
```

`

Comment: there should be `return` statement instead of `echo`

Comment: yes i am aware that i'm using echo for test purposes. i think $_REQUEST data is null since it won't proceed with the database insertion

Answer (score 0):

Code, check for `null` too:

```
<?php
function coordinates()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) && isset($_REQUEST['lng']) && !empty($_REQUEST['lat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['lng'])) {
        $lat = $_POST['lat'];
        $lng = $_POST['lng'];
        return "OK";
    } else {
        return "not ok";
    }
}

$data = $this->vm_model->insertcoordinates($lat,$lng);
return $data;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. i have tried this and the problem still persists. the query still won't insert because the data received is null. I was wondering if the problem is on the php side or on the android side?

Comment: it is on android side, bcoz I have checked that request data is empty or not.

Comment: you can check in the function that what comes in `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: should i store the data into sessions?

Comment: no. check whether your request is working or not? what comes in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: i can't exactly check it cause the moment i open the link the $_REQUEST expires. or am i wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by expire? you have to pass the params too

Comment: the android sends the data to the controller. and the moment the controller exits the data sent will become null again right?